# How to enable Quick edit in SharePoint 2013 using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, list-view, quick-edit

Without using Powershell, we are able to enable the Quick Edit as mentioned in the below URL:

[SharePoint 2013: Create Custom List Template and Set Default View To Datasheet View Programmatically](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/sharepoint-2013-create-custom-list-template-set-default-vi/)

But we cannot use this in other environment as that environment doesn't use Visual Studio.

So , can anyone please suggest me a way to enable Quick edit in SharePoint 2013 using **PowerShell**.

**Note**: We even tried selecting all the check-boxes using OOB features. It was of no use.

Thanks in advance.

The screen shot of the list attached below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am understanding that you would want to create a list with a Datasheet view. The key property is

> SPViewType=Grid , whose enum value is 2048 [Refer here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spviewcollection.spviewtype?view=sharepoint-server)

Please find the code below where I create a view.

```
#Get destination site and list
$web = Get-SPWeb "https://devintranet.spdev/forms/"
$list = $web.Lists["tester"]

$viewTitle = "SampleDVView2"
#Add the column names from the ViewField property to a string collection
$viewFields = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
$viewFields.Add("Title") > $null
#Query property
$viewQuery = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE'/></OrderBy>"
#RowLimit property
$viewRowLimit = 50
#Paged property
$viewPaged = $true
#DefaultView property
$viewDefaultView = $true


#Create the view in the destination list
$newview = $list.Views.Add($viewTitle, $viewFields, $viewQuery, $viewRowLimit, $viewPaged, $viewDefaultView,2048,$false)
```

Comment: The following error in powershell script:                                                                                                                                  
       You cannot call a method on null values expression -                                                                         ($newview = $list.Views.Add($viewTitle, $viewFields, $viewQuery, $viewRowLimit, $viewPaged, $viewDefaultView,2048,$false))

Comment: was the $list property empty ? can you try printing $list (which is a list reference)

Comment: Yes the list propert was empty. Thankyou for helping me to identify it.  The new view is created, but still the Quick edit is not enabled. Can you please tell me how to enable the Quick Edit in this view.

Comment: Can you share us screenshots in your question? It will really be useful to understand the issue. By default, datasheet views should have a quick edit view.

Comment: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/12/fix-quick-edit-disabled-in-sharepoint-2013-issue.html - Alternatively, Can you troubleshoot with this?

Comment: Yes we already did troubleshoot with that. As it was not working then thought to run through a PowerShell. The screenshot of the list is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PowerShell command to enable Quick Edit in an existing list:

```
$WebURL="http://spsite"
$ListName="listname"
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$List = $Web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName)
$List.DisableGridEditing=$false
$List.Update()
```

Besides, we can enable it via list settings->Advanced settings->select “yes” for Quick Edit section, if it doesn’t work in your environment, you can check the article to troubleshoot:

[Fix Quick Edit Disabled in SharePoint 2013 Issue](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/12/fix-quick-edit-disabled-in-sharepoint-2013-issue.html)

Comment: I am getting the following error:                                                                                              1) The property 'DisableGridEditing' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the propert exists and can be set.                                                                                                            2) You cannot call method on a null values expression ($List.update)

Comment: Whether you use SharePoint 2013 management shell to run this command? If not, run it as administrator and check again.

Comment: Yes I used SP 2013 management shell and as an administrator only

Comment: what's the kind of list and view which has this issue? Have you replace the site name and list name with your own site and list in the command above?

Comment: Yes. I have changed them according to my requirement. Still the Quick edit is not enabled

Comment: Only a list or all lists cannot enable Quick Edit? Whether you add custom code in the list view page? Try to edit the page and check again.

Comment: In all the lists quick edit is not enabled